Training Kernel Ridge Regression with subsets of features contributing to the final target
I'm working on a machine learning problem using Kernel Ridge Regression (KRR) in Python with scikit-learn. My goal is to train a kernel where subsets of features contribute to the target prediction.
For example, we know that in a standard case, the training will be done for:
Feature data X ((n_samples, n_features)) -> Y (n_samples)
What I want to do is, training a regression model has mapping with dimensions: (n_subset) -> y_subset
So the (n_features) consists of subgroups with size (n_subset) with analogous origins by nature, where their patterns are repeated similarly but values are not rigorously the same.
Say (n_features) = (n_subset)*(n_terms).
As a premature solution, I have implemented a model where each subset of features contributes equally to the final prediction. Here is a sample code:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def train_kernel_with_weights(X, Y, n_subset, kernel_param_grid):
    nset, nfeat_total = X.shape
    n_kerterm = nfeat_total // n_subset  # number of Kernel-predicted terms, to be summated to the total
    X_sub_rearr = X.reshape(nset * n_kerterm, n_subset)
    
    kr1 = GridSearchCV(KernelRidge(), param_grid=kernel_param_grid, cv=5)

    # Here, tested 'equal weight' scheme that arbitrarily assume each (n_subset)->y_subset term 
    # contributes equally to the total Y.
    kr1.fit(X_sub_rearr, np.repeat(Y/n_kerterm, n_kerterm))
    
    return kr1
    
# Given a kernel with mapping (n_subset -> value), get subset-summated prediction values
def predict_krrsum_1(n_subset, kr1, X):
    nset, nfeat_total = X.shape
    n_kerterm = nfeat_total // n_subset

    # split each data point's features with n_subset (probably triplets)
    X_sub_rearr = X.reshape(nset*n_kerterm,n_subset)
    Y_krrsub_flat = kr1.predict(X_sub_rearr)   # 1d array (nset*n_kerterm)
    Y_krrsub = Y_krrsub_flat.reshape(-1,n_kerterm)   # (nset, n_kerterm)
    Y_krrsum_1 = np.sum(Y_krrsub,axis=1)
    return Y_krrsum_1

Then my question is: for the function of kernel training: train_kernel_with_weights,
how can I optimize weights for the subsets instead of arbitrarily using equal weights?
